# Formatting Excel sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, printing, excel, excel-2007

**What I have**

Excel 2007 worksheets.
Info in Range A1:C48 (fixed) in multiple sheets in the same workbook.

**What I need**

I need to print this selection in a Letter size paper with normal margins.
But the condition is i am required to fit the width of the selection i.e. 3 columns to 1 page.
I must keep the widths of the columns constant to maintain a constant font size.
I would like to do this using VBA.

Here is the code i tried:

```
Sub printing()
    Dim w1 As Single, w2 As Single, w3 As Single
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    w1 = 62
    w2 = 24.71
    w3 = 22.14
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = w1
    ActiveSheet.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = w2
    ActiveSheet.Columns(3).ColumnWidth = w3

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C48").Select

    With Worksheets(i).PageSetup
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.5)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    End With
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

While this resizes the columns and sets other properties, the page break is still left untouched and when i try to print it, column 4 is also included. I don't want to manually drag the page break as this would resize the characters. I would prefer to set the column widths so that it will fit letter paper with normal margins.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly I think what you want is the `PageSetup.PrintArea` property. You could add:

```
.PrintArea= "$A$1:$C$48"
```

to your with block.

Comment: i tried your suggestion , i works out if i have a single 48 * 3 range in a worksheet. But when i have multiple such regions one below the other in the same sheet , i find i can only create a single printArea and which is a local rangename.

Comment: The original question said that the range A1:C48 was fixed and that they were located in different worksheets. So the answer to the question is correct. If you want to do it in a single worksheet look at looping through the various ranges in the worksheet, setting the `PrintArea` property, and then sending the print job with the `PrintOut` method. Make sure you test before you waste all that paper!

Comment: I am sorry about the mistake in the question, I kind of used the .PrintArea suggestion , i provided my own button for Printing in the ribbon used the users cells selection to create the PrintArea and then redirect then redirect to PrintPreview. Thanks guys...